# DeMorgan's Laws and Complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm having trouble with a mundane exercise in DeMorgan's Laws (or I think I am, at least). Let $\mathcal A$ be a collection of sets. Can I say that the following is closed under complements?

$$\left\{\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}\text{: for each $i$ and $j$, $A_{ij}$ or $A_{ij}^c\in\mathcal{A}$}\right\}$$

Basically, all I need to do is take an element of that form, then take its complement, and then rewrite it in the same form. Here's my attempt: Applying DeMorgan's laws twice,

$$\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}\Big)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^m\Big(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}\Big)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^m\bigcup_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}^c.$$

However, I'm stuck here. It'd be nice to pull out the union and call it a day, but it depends on the intersection, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=\max\{n_i:i=1,\ldots,m\}$. For each $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and each integer $k$ such that $n_i<k\le n$ let $A_{ik}=A_{in_i}$. Then

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}=\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_{ij}\;.$$

(This is merely a small technical trick to simplify the notation later on.)

For $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $F(m,n)$ be the set of functions from $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Now prove by induction on $m$ that

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_{ij}=\bigcap_{f\in F(m,n)}\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}\;;\tag{1}$$

the first couple of steps of the calculation for the induction step are

$$\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{i=1}^{m+1}\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_{ij}&=\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_{m+1,j}\right)\cup\bigcap_{f\in{}^mn}\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}\\\\
&=\bigcap_{j=1}^n\left(A_{m+1,j}\cup\bigcap_{f\in{}^mn}\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

You’ll also want to realize that if $f\in F(m,n)$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then

$$A_{m+1,j}\cup\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{m+1}A_{i,g(i)}\;,$$

where $g\in F(m+1,n)$ is defined by

$$g(i)=\begin{cases}
f(i),&\text{if }i\le m\\
j,&\text{if }i=m+1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Once you have $(1)$, you can write

$$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcap_{j=1}^nA_{ij}\right)^c=\left(\bigcap_{f\in F(m,n)}\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}\right)^c\;,$$

apply De Morgan’s laws twice to the righthand side, and end up with a union of intersections, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt and filling answer. I must be missing something however, as I'm having the same problem as with copper.hat's response. After applying De Morgan's laws twice to the righthand side, you have $\cup\cap A^c$'s, where the union's are still dependent on the size of the intersection's no? Isn't that how the # of $F$'s are evaluated?

Comment: @user94049: You’re welcome. You get $$\bigcup_{f\in F(m,n)}\bigcap_{i=1}^mA_{i,f(i)}^c\;,$$ which is fine: it’s a finite union of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr{A}$ or their complements. $F(m,n)$ can be a rather large set, much larger than $m$ or $n$, but all that matters is that it’s finite, and that for each element of it you’re calculating a finite union of members of $\mathscr{A}$ or their complements.

Answer (score 1):

Less formally:

$\bigcap_{i=1}^m\bigcup_{j=1}^{n_i}A_{ij}^c = (\bigcup_{j_1=1}^{n_1}A_{1j_1}^c) \cap \cdots \cap (\bigcup_{j_m=1}^{n_m}A_{mj_m}^c) = \bigcup_{j_1=1}^{n_1} \cdots \bigcup_{j_m=1}^{n_m} \bigcap_{k=1}^m A_{kj_k}^c$.

Comment: Don't the unions still depend on the intersections here, and not the other way around?

Comment: No. You can think of $m$ as being a constant function of the index $(j_1,...,j_m)$.